# converting class to hooks array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

i'm trying to convert class to hooks, my problem is this part '[event.target.id]: event.target.value,', how to convert it ?

my code :

```js
 this.setState({
      helperText: {
        ...this.state.helperText,
        [event.target.id]: helperText,
      },
      error: {
        ...this.state.error,
        [event.target.id]: error,
      },
      [event.target.id]: event.target.value,
    });
```

what i have done:

```js
setHelperText({
    ...helperText,
    [event.target.id]: helperText,
  })
setError({
    ...error,
    [event.target.id]: error,
  })
```

how to convert last part ?

Comment: Can you post your class component and function component code that you are trying to convert?

Comment: Are you tracking `event.target.id` somewhere? Otherwise, how do you access these properties?

Answer (score 1):

You can put record or map into `useState`

```js
const [values, setValues] = useState({});

setValues(prevValues => ({ ...prevValues, [event.target.id]: event.target.value }));
```

or

```js
const [values, setValues] = useState(new Map());

setValue(prevValues => new Map(prevValues).set(event.target.id, event.target.value))
```

Also, you might want to switch you structure to update everything at once:

```js
const [state, setState] = useState({});

setState(prevState => {
  const value = {
    value: event.target.value,
    helperText,
    error,
  };

  return { ...prevState, [event.target.id]: value };
});
```

Note! You should use function version of a `setState` if your next value depends on previous value. https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: the last one updating everyting at once, where are these two in your code: [event.target.id]: helperText and [event.target.id]: error,

Comment: @waleedd32 I made it based on your first code snippet. This values expected to be provided, just as `event`